# How to plot with pyplot from a script file in Google Colab

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, ipython, google-colaboratory

I am trying to show a plot to the notebook from a python script, but all I get is a text output showing me the type() output of the figure.I have something like this:
[image: Setting matplotlib backend to inline, then calling the script.]

This is my script (a very simplified version of my actual script, but same concept).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,5,3,2,4,2,3,4,2]

plt.plot(x)
plt.show()
```

I have also tried setting the backend to notebook, but I get the same result. If I plot some data from the console (writing python directly into the code textbox, the plot works fine). I have searched for the answer in a lot of forums, and even the official Google notebook to plotting in Colab says that the plot should work fine from within a script.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Instead of calling

```
!python plot.py
```

Use this instead

```
%run plot.py
```

It will show the plot normally.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Could you explain the difference?

Comment: %run will load the code line-by-line, as if you type it all in Colab. !python will run it separately, so it cannot access the output cell, and cannot display.