# In Colab, why are images not displayed in executed files when they are in an identical code cell?

Tags: image, google-colaboratory

In Colab, the following  code snippet will display (as expected) the image specified:

```
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
import cv2
#from PIL import Image
img = cv2.imread('drive/MyDrive/beagle2.jpg')
cv2_imshow(img)
```

If, however, this code is run as a Python file, there is an error:
AttributeError: module 'PIL' has no attribute 'Image'

Why the difference? And what has module 'PIL" got to do with anything?
I have tried various image display methods and while I can get them all to work in a code cell, in an executed file, they either give an error, a text description of the image file or nothing.

I need to run my code as file in order to pass parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer:

instead of running

```
!python yourScript.py
```

run

```
%run yourScript.py
```

and images will display with pyplot,cv2_imshow etc.

cf. [How to plot with pyplot from a script file in Google Colab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59977900/how-to-plot-with-pyplot-from-a-script-file-in-google-colab)

This solution took ages to find and why it works is unclear to me. Is it just another not very well documented  feature of Colab?

Answer (score 0):

If

```
from PIL import Image
```

is put at the top of the file (and only at the top. Why?) then the following description of the image is produced:

<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=259x201 at 0x7F05007C5DA0>

but the image itself is still not displayed.